# What is causing Notepad++ to show me an article about poverty?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Earlier today, I was trying to close out of Notepad++. I must have mashed the keyboard sequence wrong, because instead of closing, Internet Explorer opened with the article on "[Poverty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poverty)".

A quick check of the keyboard shortcuts from the "Run" menu revealed that there was an option to "Lanuch in IE" (one option amoung several other browsers). However, this just opens the entire text file in the browsers.

How in the world was I redirected to this page? **Is Notepad++ trying to tell me something?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some reflection, and some more digging into the list of Notepad++ keyboard shortcuts, the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> does a Wikipedia Search for whatever word or phrase is highlighted in the text file. I was ranking some items "Excellent", "Good", and "Poor".

The final term--as you may have guessed--was selected for some reason, thus leading to the multiple layers of redirection & confusion.

(As you know, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> would have simply closed the program.)